# GTM CSS selector to extract text

Tags: css, google-tag-manager

I am having a problem with extracting text after a form is successfully submitted.
[I want to extract the boxed text and add it to a dom element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pJi8.png)

I am using Chorme Console for checking. As shown below, this is the max i can traverse. Could you please help me reach the boxed text as shown in the diagram?

**document.querySelector("body > div.body > div > section > div > div > div.col-md-12.main-content > div.alert.alert-success.fade.in > a")**

Comment: the message text needs to be wrapped in an element of it's own to be selectable when it's surrounded by other child elements, a `span` element perhaps. If you use ID's you won't have to be so specific to target it.

Comment: Any ways to track it in the current scenario without disturbing the developer ?

Comment: With Custom HTML, or maybe even with a Custom Variable you can get the text of the parent element, relative to {{Click Element}}.

Comment: You can probably target the parent `alert` div if you can live with that anchor tag being passed in as well.

Comment: @kgrg that is the text which is Displayed after the form is submitted on a new page. Click element does not work

Comment: @Jasmine your method would be sensible if the HTML could be altered but as I understand it it can't. Elements can  be targeted in other ways, as the question has shown, you can then extract the text only. I've posted the method in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the parent element:

```
 el = document.querySelector("body > div.body > div > section > div > div > div.col-md-12.main-content > div.alert.alert-success.fade.in");
```

Then extract the text only by

```
thetext = el.innerText;
```

and removing the 'x' (a more sophisticated solution would find the text of the a element, not relying on it being 'x', and removing that from the string). Of course you are relying on knowing that there isn't additional text in there at some point as you don't have control over the HTML you are traversing, so if some other text was inserted you would get that too - but that's unavoidable.

Comment: remove the `>a` from the selector because that would just return the value of the close button: 'x', not the message text

Comment: @Jasmine yes thanks for spotting this. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. I made use of A Haworth's solution with a little monification. Code used is :function() {
  var el = document.querySelector("body > div.body > div > section > div > div > div.col-md-12.main-content > div.alert.alert-success.fade.in");
  var thetext = el.textContent;
  return thetext;
}